# Why this simple code isn't working (move_uploaded_file();)

Tags: php, file-upload, windows-7

**The php configuration is correct, I saw people who worked with this code and it worked. But in my case I try many things and it never upload the file, and it doesn't tell me that there is a syntax error.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {
        $name_file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $location = "Imagenes/";
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location.$name_file);
    }
?>

<form method="POST" action="Upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
    <div style="margin-top: 50%;">
        <label>Inserte la imagen que desee subir:</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="file" id="file">
        <input type="submit" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 40%;" class="btn btn-outline-success" name="Upload" value="Upload" required="on">
    </div>
</form>**
```

Comment: what's the OS that is running under? You also state that there isn't a syntax error, yet I don't see any error reporting codes in what you posted. The HTML is also missing here. Plus, is this in separate files or just the one?

Comment: I'm using XAMPP, now I've updated the post. Thank you!

Comment: that's not the OS, that's the interpreter. The OS meaning the "Operating System". Is this Windows, LINUX/UNIX, Mac? That could make a difference. Are you not using `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your code? If not, run it again and then update your post to contain the errors, if any.

Comment: Oh sorry, i'm very stupid when I speak english, the OS is Windows 7, I'm going to try it now.

Comment: check the path and make sure the folder can be written to. Most of the time, that's what the problem is.

Comment: I can't see any error using your code in the top, and the folder can be written.

Comment: Are your code file and `Imagenes` folder is at the same working location(same working directory)? Is folder has write permission?Is the path is correct?Show us your folder structure. Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` before `if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {` and check